# 2D JTextField array setText using MouseClicked/MousePressed

Tags: java, arrays, mouseevent, jtextfield, mouselistener

So I have a JTextField array called `fields` and I have a string called `value` (the value of `value` is replaced when I click on a button). What I want is when I click on one of the JTextFields, I want to put the `value` in it (using `setText`, maybe).

```
private JTextField[][] fields;
fields = new JTextField[totalX][totalY];
```

Is there a way to do this with a MouseClicked/MousePressed event. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FocusListener` instead of mouse listener. Example:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                field.setText(value);
            }
        });
```

Tutorial - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html